# Adding a new path in PATH

Tags: path

On a server I own; Git was not working. I found that Git is installed in
`/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git`.

So, to make Git available to be used without full path; I logged into ssh as root. Then I modified `~/.bash_profile` (`vim .bash_profile`) and appended `/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin` with PATH.

PATH now looks like:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin
```

With this; git is now working fine. But I just want to make sure that nothing is messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look messed up, and you put the directory at the end of your PATH, so commands in that directory cannot mask some system command.

Here are a few additional things you can check:

- Are there any strange commands in the directory that have nothing to do with `git`, in particular ones that look like mistyped "common" commands (e.g. `mroe` as mistyped `more`).
- The write permissions on the directory should be for root only
- Reconsider why you need `root` to use `git`, if it is for revision control of e.g. the `/etc` directory then that is fine. If you do normal software development, you should reconsider setting that up so you can do that as normal user.